# Adding JSON.NET parsing errors into JsonExtensionData

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an object like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    int bar;
    [JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, object> Catchall;
}
```

And JSON like so:
`jsonString = { "bar": "not an int", "dink": 1 }`

So if I `var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString)`

`bar` will fail to deserialize into the class `Foo` since it's of the wrong type, but is it possible to have it be inserted into the `[JsonExtensionData] Catchall` dictionary?

Comment: If you do this, later if you re-serialize your `Foo` class you'll end up with duplicated `"bar"` properties in the JSON, which can be problematic.  See for instance [JSON.Net Duplicate properties on Serialization of derived object where base contains Dictionary Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434251/json-net-duplicate-properties-on-serialization-of-derived-object-where-base-cont).

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the property `bar` with [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm), then manually add and remove its value in the `Catchall` dictionary in appropriate [serialization callbacks](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbackAttributes.htm):

```
public class Foo
{
    const string barName = "bar";

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? Bar { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Catchall;

    [OnSerializing]
    void OnSerializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        if (Catchall == null)
            Catchall = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (Bar != null)
            Catchall[barName] = Bar.Value;
    }

    [OnSerialized]
    void OnSerialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        if (Catchall != null)
            Catchall.Remove(barName);
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Catchall != null)
        {
            object value;
            if (Catchall.TryGetValue(barName, out value))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        Bar = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Bar = (int)JToken.FromObject(value);
                    }
                    Catchall.Remove(barName);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Value \"{0}\" of {1} was not an integer", value, barName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have changed `bar` to be a `public int? Bar { get; set; }`.  A null value indicates that an integral value for `Bar` was not deserialized, and so, when re-serializing, the value in the dictionary (if any) should not be superseded by the value of the property.